# @Html.ActionLink with language attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization, html.actionlink

I believe this has to be very easy but I just cant figure it out.

I have custom route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultLocalized",
                url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { language = "EN", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

In the controller i have

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
            ViewBag.language = Internationalization.SetCultureFromUrl(requestContext, "EN");
        }
```

and the question is, how to specify language attribute in `@Html.ActionLink` ?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new { language = someValue }, null)`

Comment: awesome, it works, thank you !!